How to tag another user in a post from custom LinkedIn automation solution
I am creating a webapp from where I can post to LinkedIn directly using the LinkedIn APIs. I want to also tag a LinkedIn user when I am sending the post content. However I cannot find any API endpoints or easy methods (like copy-paste profile URL into the content) that could work.
I saw that we could tag someone if we know their urn:person:person_id. But we cannot know the person_id until the person authenticates to use my app with LinkedIn. Or we could use the Profile API to retrieve a person's profile with their first name and thereby, hopefully, get their person_id (couldn't try this since I don't have access to the API currently).
Any help/direction/suggestions/hacks on how to achieve this feature would be appreciated. Thank You.
References:

Retrieve Other Member's Profile - LinkedIn Profile API


So I figured it out eventually. We can use the People Typeahead API to tag others.
